# Backbone with TastyPie: DELETE does a Redirect

Tags: django, backbone.js, tastypie

I'm using a combination of django-tastypie & backbone.

I'm trying to do a `DELETE` but I get a `301 Moved Permanently` response.

Here's the message from Firebug:

```
DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/1/grocery_item/2 301 Moved Permanently.
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/1/grocery_item/
```

My code is below:

```python
class GroceryListItemResource(ModelResource):

    grocery_list = fields.ForeignKey(GroceryListResource, 'grocery_list', full=True)
    grocery_item = fields.ForeignKey(GroceryItemResource, 'grocery_item', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = GroceryListItem.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'list_items'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'delete']
        include_resource_uri = False
        excludes = ['created_at', 'updated_at']
        filtering = {
            'grocery_list': ALL
        }
        authorization= Authorization()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was missing a trailing slash. 127.0.0.1:8000/api/1/grocery_item/2/ works.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the delete code, there's really no reason it should be returning a 302. What happens when you make that request via CURL? is it possible that Firefox is intercepting and changing the request somehow?  Are you seeing it come through to your server process as a DELETE request at that URL?